# Spacy 3.1 NLP is not working after deploying on Azure app service

Tags: azure, nlp, spacy

Working on a project where I need to train a model using Spacy 3.1, All is working as expected on the local system, but when I deploy it on the Azure app service training model is not working [seems to be like it got stuck]. If anyone has faced a similar kind of issue please guide me?

Comment: You need to get the error output or some more details before anyone can help you with this.